# Foundation sticky magellan not working

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, magellan

Im trying to create a little nav that takes me to certain divs on click. It does that, but at the moment it just snaps down to the div. Instead i want a smooth transition down just like it says it should in the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html).

Also, as i scroll down to the certain divs i want the neccessary nav li's to be highlighted. But when i inspect element on them they dont highlight as i scroll down the page at the moment.. It's definetely picking up the css cdn but the js one im not so sure.

**Head** (Im using a cdn)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4-rc2/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4-rc2/foundation.min.css">


<section id="div1_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div1_wrapper">

<div class="leftHeaders" data-sticky-container>
    <ul class="sticky" data-sticky data-magellan>
        <li><a href="#div4_wrapper">4th page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div3_wrapper">3rd page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div2_wrapper">2nd page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div1_wrapper">1st page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</section>
<section id="div2_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div2_wrapper">

</section>
<section id="div3_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div3_wrapper">

</section>
<section id="div4_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div4_wrapper">
</section>
```

Comment: [ https://jsfiddle.net/ek4sp8w5/1/ ] something like this scrolling ??

Comment: No, more like [this] (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/magellan.html). See how the options on the right side get highlighted as you scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).foundation();
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none outside;
}

   
 
#div2_wrapper,
#div3_wrapper,
#div4_wrapper {
 height:100%;
 border:1px solid blue;
}

.sticky ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4-rc2/foundation.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.2.4-rc2/foundation.min.css">


<section id="div1_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div1_wrapper">
  <div class="leftHeaders" data-sticky-container>
    <div class="sticky" data-sticky-on="small" data-sticky data-margin-top="0" data-anchor="content">
      <ul data-magellan>
        <li><a href="#div4_wrapper">4th page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div3_wrapper">3rd page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div2_wrapper">2nd page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div1_wrapper">1st page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="div2_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div2_wrapper">

</section>
<section id="div3_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div3_wrapper">
  
</section>
<section id="div4_wrapper" data-magellan-target="div4_wrapper">
  
</section>
```